# preserving field order in a 'join'

Tags: shell, join

Let's say I have two files like this:

```
1   a   one ...
2   b   two ...
3   c   three   ...
4   d   four    ...
5   e   five    ...
6   f   six ...
```

and

```
a
c
f
```

Is there a way, **not knowing the number of columns in file 1** (or not having to repeat each field), I can use join to get the matching lines

```
1   a   one ...
3   c   three   ...
6   f   six ...
```

I've tried

```
join -1 2 -o 1.0 file1 file2
```

like you'd write `$0` to get all fields in `awk`, but I obviously get `invalid field number`.

Comment: dunno about using `join` for this case, but you can use `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' file2 file1`

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which fields to print in which order or print all fields in default order. But you cannot print 'the rest of the fields'.

From `man join`:

```
-o FORMAT
       obey FORMAT while constructing output line
[...]
Any FIELD is a field number counted from 1. FORMAT is one or
more  comma or blank separated specifications, each being
'FILENUM.FIELD' or '0'.
```

You could use awk:

```
awk -v regex="$(head -c -1 file2 | tr '\n' '|')" '$2 ~ regex' file1
```

- Remove last newline of file2 and replace newlines wit '|', the regex will be `a|c|f`
- Match the second field of file1 with that regex

Or use the awk solution of Sundeep especially if file2 contains special characters.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, is it wrong to explain why he gets an error?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just swap the 2 first fields :

```
| awk '{swap=$1;$1=$2;$2=swap;print $0}'
```